# getting a Twitter::Cursor object with the Twitter gem

Tags: ruby, twitter, rubygems

I'm playing around with the [Ruby Twitter gem](https://github.com/sferik/twitter) and wish to use the methods that are available on the Cursor object. For example, using the Twitter::Cursor I'm supposed to be able to get a an array of all friends by doing

```
client.friends.to_a
```

or get a most recent follower with

```
client.friends.first
```

However, in my attempt below, when tried to do `client.friends.first` for kanyewest,  I got an error which showed that I'm using the `Twitter::User` object, not the `Twitter::Cursor`

`undefined method`friends' for #

How can I use the gem to get a cursor object that will allow me to query Kanye's friends. 
client.friends.to_a

Note, I read the documentation for creating a new cursor object but I found it a little abstract. I'm not sure if you're supposed to call the constructor directly? If so, please show me how I'd do that

```
- (Twitter::Cursor) initialize(attrs, key, klass, request)
```

My Failing code

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
 require 'rubygems'
 require 'twitter'

 client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key     = "8nwa....."
  config.consumer_secret  = "Wj20r....."
  config.access_token     = "363......"
  config.access_token_secret = "7eydU2n....."
end

kanyewest = client.user("kanyewest")
puts kanyewest.friends.first
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`client.friends("kanyewest").first` should work. `friends` is a method on `client` not on `Twitter::User`

Comment: > client.friends("kanyewest").first.screen_name
=> "KimKardashian"